# Insert subsequent numbers in a substitution pattern

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I want to insert subsequent numbers whenever there a regex matches.

I do this in terminal using `for` command and either `perl` or `sed`.

Is there a way to do this in vim?

Basically I want this:

```
 This is a command
```

To turn to this:

```
 This is a1 comma2nd
```

where I am using the regex `a`

Comment: If you have a command that reads a file from stdin and outputs it to stdout, named `addMatchNumbers` that takes as its first argument the regex, you could use vim filters : eg write `:%! addMatchNumbers a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
let g:i = 0
function! Increment()
    let g:i = g:i + 1
    return g:i
endfunction
```

And then:

```
:%s/pattern/\=submatch(0) . Increment()/g
```

BTW, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951533/search-and-replace-with-incremented-values-in-vim) is pretty similar.

Comment: Or just `:%s/pattern\zs/\=Increment()/g`.  Exercise to the astute reader: make `Increment()` reset the counter at the beginning of each line, rather than count occurrences from the beginning of file.

Comment: Nice :) (To reset counter, I'd rather use `:global` with `let g:i = 0` followed by a similar substitution on current matching line).