# Search and Replace in each PATTERN with counter

Tags: search

I am trying to search and replace certain pattern "\x" to REPLACE_counter. Where counter goes from $0$ to $N$. The text is

```
\x    & \x       & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{1-1}
\x    & \x       & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{1-1}
```

I found the next command

```
let i=1 | g/\\x/.,.s//\='REPLACE_'.i/ | let i=i+1
```

but it only works for the first match in each line, i.e. I get

```
REPLACE_1   & \x       & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{1-1}
REPLACE_2    & \x       & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{1-1}
```

How can I modify that command to get

```
REPLACE_1   & REPLACE_2 & REPLACE_3& REPLACE_4& \xREPLACE_5 \\ \cline{1-1}
REPLACE_6    & REPLACE_7      & REPLACE_8    & REPLACE_9    & REPLACE_10 \\ \cline{1-1}
```

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/insert-subsequent-numbers-in-a-substitution-pattern/4751#4751

Answer (score 2):

In vim 7.4.2008 and later, you can do this with substitute and `execute()`:

```
:let i = 1
:%s/\\x/\='REPLACE_'.i.execute('let i+=1')/g
```

`\=` allows you to use an expression as the replacement string.  `execute()` invokes an ex command (`let`) in an expression.  In this case `execute()` returns empty string.  We use `/g` to replace multiple instances per line.

Comment: E117: Unknown function: execute

Comment: you should update your vim then